# Double array operation to single array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public void calculatePercentage(int exam[][])
    {
        int perc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < examen.length; i++)
        {
            for (int[] score : exam)
                perc += score;
            perc /= exam.length;
        }
    }
```

Hello,
I am really stuck at this one. I want to create a new mathod calculatePercentages given the parameter exam[][]. The double array exam holds 3 rows of elements. What the method has to do is simple calculate the sum of each row. The answer is probably quite simple, but I just don't know how to do it.
For a single array, I guess the code is:

```
double perc = 0;
    for(int score : exam)
    {
            perc += score;
    }
    perc /= (exam.length);
    return perc;
```

The exam[][] could look like:

|10 12 18 5 3  |
|12 3 5 15 20  |
|20 15 13 11 9 |

The output percentage[] should like:

{48,55,68} Each element of percentage[] is the sum of the elements of 1 row of exam[]

Comment: Show an example input, and an example output, because it's not clear at all.

Comment: yeah it's unclear, and why the name of the method is calculatePercentage if it is just summing it up?

Comment: see above, I typed a possible input and output

Comment: See jlordo's answer, then. But why the hell are you calling this method calculatePercentage, since it doesn't calculate any percentage?

Comment: because it are 5 results on /20. Take the sum of these 5 results, makes a result on /100? And there you have a percentage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The double array exam holds 3 rows of elements. What the method has to do is simple calculate the sum of each row.

The name makes no sense, but it does what you want it to do.

```
public int[] calculatePercentage(int exam[][]) {
    int[] sums = new int[exam.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < exam.length; i++) {
         int sum = 0;
         for (int j = 0; j < exam[i].length; j++) {
              sum += exam[i][j];
         }
         sums[i] = sum;
    }
    return sums;
}
```

Also a double array would be `double[]`, you are talking about two dimensional int arrays `int[][]`

**EDIT**

[Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) pointed out a shorter solution is possible:

```
public int[] calculatePercentage(int exam[][]) {
    int[] sums = new int[exam.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < exam.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < exam[i].length; j++) {
              sums[i] += exam[i][j];
         }
    }
    return sums;
}
```

or even just

```
public int[] calculatePercentage(int exam[][]) {
    int[] sums = new int[exam.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < exam.length; i++)
         for (int j = 0; j < exam[i].length; j++)
              sums[i] += exam[i][j];
    return sums;
}
```

but I still prefer the first one, for it's readability.

Comment: +1 but you don't need temp `sum` variable since you already have `sums[i]` which is 0 at the beginning. You can just `for (int j = 0; j < exam[i].length; j++) sums[i]+=exam[i][j];`

Comment: indeed, 2dimensional array, sorry for that

Comment: @jlordo, 2nd line, doesn't it has to be int[] sums = new int[exam[i].length];?
Because now you will make an array that is 5 long, and I need one of 3 long

Comment: in the second line `i` can't be resolved to a variable. What the code does is create an array that's size is the amount of rows of `exams`. Every element will be the sum of the corresponding row, just as in your input output example. So my code is correct, or I have a severe misunderstanding of your question.

Comment: @user1873613 in your input output example `exam.length` is 3, and `exam[i].length` is 5 for `i=0,1,2`

Comment: Thanks guys! This code gives no errors, I just keep on coding the rest of my class and then I will test it. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < exam.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < exam[i].length; j++) {
            sum += exam[i][j];
        }

    }
```

using for each

```
for (int x[] : exam) {
      for (int y : x) {

        sum += y;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mohammod hossain, but I already got a solution. I appreciate it of you.